# How could I enable docker remote api on mac osx

Tags: macos, docker, boot2docker

My containers are working now. But I can not access docker remote API.

And the docker setting folder is located `/Users/lala/.boot2docker`

> Get nothing back by curl http://192.168.59.103:2376/info

## .zshrc

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/lala/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a pkcs12 certificate to get curl to talk to docker when it's in secure/TLS mode. My answer is based on this [post](http://www.craigjellick.com/curl-docker-api-mac-boot2docker/). I'll assume that you run the pkcs12 creation command (openssl) in the current directory).

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey $DOCKER_CERT_PATH/key.pem -in $DOCKER_CERT_PATH/cert.pem \
-name b2d-client-side -out b2d-client-side.p12 -password pass:mysecret  

curl -k --cert b2d-client-side.p12:mysecret \
https://$(boot2docker ip):2376/info
```